# How can I sort by created_at on this Rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

Given the following AR query to retrieve messages as conversations (group them by sender_id), how can I display recent message first? This query is displaying the first message sent but not the most recent one.

```
User.find(1).messages.select("DISTINCT ON (messages.sender_id(created_at)) * ")
  .where("messages.sender_id = (?)",friend.id)
  .group("messages.sender_id, messages.updated_at, messages.id, messages.user_id, messages.sent, messages.read")
```

I'm a little lost in where and how to add a order clause here.

Comment: which language you used to write query? this is not plain SQL

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add `rails` tag to the question.

Comment: Try `.order(created_at: "DESC")` at the end

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `.order("created_at desc")` ?

Comment: order doesn't seem to be working when using `distinct` for some reason. I can't use group without using distinct since is a postgres db.

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY` and `DISTINCT` do not work together.

The proper way to do it is to do a `group by` and `order by` instead.

The big problem is that `SELECT *` does not work with `GROUP BY` and so you have to give up on one of:

- `GROUP BY`
- `DISTINCT`
- `ORDER BY`

One option is you can change the `SELECT *` to list all columns manually and those which are not expected to be grouped by can be put in aggregates like `min()` (which is what I do in my SQL queries.

I don't use ORMs but hopefully this will give you an idea of what to do esp. since you are already pretty close to the SQL anyway.